# running multiple projects on same port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have two spring projects. One project having web-socket implementation which sends messages to the client and second project have some other services and classes. Before in the client side, I am defining two proxies. One for main services, another one for receiving web-socket messages and I have to run both the projects on different-different ports. Now I want both the projects to run on the same port. Is there any way to do that. I also have a doubt that once first project  is hosted on a port ( suppose 8080 ), will web-socket push notification work properly on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to run both projects on same port there are other ways you can achieve this. You can use a gateway (For ex: [kong](https://konghq.com/kong-community-edition/)) service or package your applications and deploy on a tomcat server. I prefer deploying applications to tomcat (If you don't have many services) as you need to put extra efforts to maintain gateway.